# How can I remove the border style from a text input on mobile safari?

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari

If I have a normal  input element it will show a rounded border with what appears to be an inset shadow.

Any ideas how I can remove this shadow?

Comment: Have you tried setting the CSS `border` and `background-color` properties explicitly?

Comment: Yes I've tried border. What difference would background colour make?

Comment: try it. In FF, defining both border and background colour switches the element into the browser's own rendering mode (instead of the OS's)

Comment: Still no luck. I tried this:
    border: 0px solid;
    background-color: White;

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try

```
-webkit-appearance: none;
```

Answer (score 10):

If you just want to remove the blue border use this: `-webkit-focus-ring-color: none`